# Star Wars: The Bad Batch, where does it go in the timeline?

Tags: star-wars, timeline, the-bad-batch

I'm trying to figure out where the Bad Batch goes in the (Disney) Star Wars timeline.
It happens at the very end of the Clone Wars (or just after the wars) as far as I can tell, so my guess is that it is set just before or parallel to events in Episode III, Revenge of the Sith.
It probably is also set AFTER the Clone War animated series (not sure, haven't seen those).

Can anyone narrow it down further (or correct me if I'm wrong)?

Comment: Forgive me, but doesn't it start with the execution of order 66? That should be a pretty big identifier..

Comment: @Gnemlock It does start with that as I gather from various sources (I haven't seen the series myself yet). Problem is that I'm very unfamiliar with Disney canon Star Wars and haven't seen any of the Disney stuff yet. So I don't have a good grip on the current state of the timeline. I'm trying to establish that first and then start watching stuff in in-universe chronological order. Watching out-of-order doesn't mesh well with my slight touch of OCD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series starts at about the same time as Episode III, Revenge of the Sith. A key event occurs in the middle of the movie that also occurs right at the start of the first episode of Bad Batch.

This same event also takes place in the very final episode of The Clone Wars series, so it's pretty easy to place these three works into the timeline: The Clone Wars lead into Revenge of the Sith, and the Bad Batch follows straight on.